# why the processing is sometimes terminated , sometimes not

Tags: sql-server, error-handling

```
DECLARE @Error int;
INSERT INTO Person.BusinessEntityContact
 (BusinessEntityID
 ,PersonID
 ,ContactTypeID)
 VALUES
 (0,0,1);
SELECT @Error = @@ERROR;
PRINT ‘The Value of @Error is ‘ + CONVERT(varchar, @Error);
```

I got :

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 4 The INSERT statement conflicted
>   with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   “FK_BusinessEntityContact_Person_PersonID”....The statement has been
>   terminated. The Value of @Error is 547

that means the process was still going on after the error was thrown.

But if I try create a table(run the below script twice to trigger the error) as:

```
CREATE TABLE OurIFTest(
 Col1 int PRIMARY KEY
 );
IF @@ERROR != 0
 PRINT 'Problems!';
ELSE
 PRINT 'Everything went OK!';
```

then I got

> Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Line 2 There is already an object named
>   'OurIFTest' in the database.

which means the process was terminated when the error was thrown.

So why the process terminated for 'Create' but not for 'Insert'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You can force the same behaviour accross errors with SET XACT_ABORT**

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON;
```

From the documentation:

> Specifies whether SQL Server automatically rolls back the current
>   transaction when a Transact-SQL statement raises a run-time error.

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-xact-abort-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

By default `XACT_ABORT = OFF` this means that different errors create different outcomes.

To force the behaviour on error to be the same, add `SET XACT_ABORT ON;` at the beginning of your script.

---

**Testing with your example**

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON;

DECLARE @Error int;
INSERT INTO Person.BusinessEntityContact
 (BusinessEntityID
 ,PersonID
 ,ContactTypeID)
 VALUES
 (0,0,1);
SELECT @Error = @@ERROR;
PRINT 'The Value of @Error is ‘ + CONVERT(varchar, @Error)'
```

**With the only error shown:**

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 17 The INSERT statement conflicted
>   with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Person". The conflict occurred in
>   database "my_test", table "Person.Person", column 'PersonID'.

---

**Also note this important statement regarding error handling and `SET XACT_ABORT`**

> The `THROW` statement honors `SET XACT_ABORT`. `RAISERROR` does not.
>   New applications should use `THROW` instead of `RAISERROR`.

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-xact-abort-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. Could you also have a look at this question? Thanks  https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/241509/when-updated-records-get-written-to-the-real-physical-pages-in-mdf-file?noredirect=1#comment476336_241509